# Multiple Sync Connections with BCS - User profile Service - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, bcs

I have added multiple sync connections using BCS external content type, created using a stored proc. One of them populated a custom User profile property (Multi-value string) properly, but others don't. We checked the stored proc and it returns the data exactly as we expect for all the external content types, but still only one of the connections work.

Is there a limitation that we can only configure 1 BCS sync connection to populate my custom user profile property?

Thanks in advance